# set TextView in HorizontalScrollView to the right

Tags: android, textview, horizontalscrollview

I have a simple construction; a TextView in a Scrollview, but I cannot make it work as I want.

The problems I get now;

- The ScrollView keeps expanded when once the TextView was larger than the width of the screen, even when I set the text of TextView to nothing.
- The TextView is on the left side.

I got the following:

```
       <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"

            android:background="@drawable/background_scrollviews_display"

            android:id="@+id/scrollViewSum">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_gravity="right">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextStyleDisplay"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fontSizeTextViewSum"

                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingDisplayTextViews"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/paddingDisplayTextViews"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right|center"

                    android:id="@+id/textViewSum"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

What I want;

- The TextView on the right;
- The ScrollView only expand when the TextView is larger than width of the screen;

I tried a lot, but I simply cannot find the right solution.

I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: add picture explaining what you want?

Comment: have you tried to set the width of the TextView to "wrap_content"?

Comment: Either set a weight or properly size your Textview. Currently TextView is the same size of its parent LinearLayout, which is the same size as its parent ScrollView

Comment: thanks, the width=wrap_content in the TextView did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a two clue to solve your problems:

1) make LinearLayout orientation Vertical, then you can position TextView on the right

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_gravity="right">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextStyleDisplay"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontSizeTextViewSum"

                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingDisplayTextViews"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/paddingDisplayTextViews"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right|center"

                android:id="@+id/textViewSum"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

2) make TextView wrap_content instead of match_parent

```
<TextView
                style="@style/TextStyleDisplay"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontSizeTextViewSum"

                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingDisplayTextViews"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/paddingDisplayTextViews"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right|center"

                android:id="@+id/textViewSum"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

make the textview width wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

I have hard coded stuff like padding and text size etc. as I did't have your dimensions, you can change it later as per your requirements.

check if following code snipet helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewSum"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="ldksjfkdlfkfldksjfkdlfkf"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```